# Java Weka count number of appearances of distinct values of an attribute

Tags: java, machine-learning, attributes, weka

I have an attribute (Using Weka!)

```
@attribute age {10-19,20-29,30-39,40-49,50-59,60-69,70-79,80-89,90-99}
```

Now, for a given `Instances data`, I want to get the number of appearances of each `Instance` at attribute `age`. So if in `data` I have 50 instances with the attribute `age 10-19`, 100 people with the attribute `age 20-29`, and 150 people with the attribute `age 30-39`, then I want to count it, and get something like:

```
age 10-19: 50
age 20-29: 100
age 30-39: 150
age 40-49: 0
age 50-59:0
...
age 90-99: 0
```

My first guess was just doing some naive approach to count each one of them using a hash map or something like that, but I think there is a better solution out there. 
Any help would be appreciated (even the naive approach).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one solution.

for attribute as index `i`, by looping through the dataset and finding the attribute value index of an `instance` by `instance.value(i)` for attribute `i`.

```
Instances training = loadData("...");
int[] countAttributes = new int[training.attribute(i).numValues()];
for(Instance instance: training){
    countAttributes[(int)instance.value(i)]++;
}
```